# All Breakpoints Show as Undefined in Flutter Projects

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Earlier today, breakpoints were working, and now they all become unverified as soon as I start the debugger.  I'm using:
VS Code 1.83.1
Dart Extension v3.74.0
Flutter Extension v3.74.0
Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Pixel 2 API 30 for my emulated phone

I have tried rebooting, doing a flutter clean, flutter pub get.  I tried a new emulator, Pixel 7 Pro API 34.  I checked for updates for Android Studio.  I tried other Flutter projects.  All Flutter projects exhibit the same behavior.  I am starting using the debugger, not run without debugging.  Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why breakpoints are not being hit or are becoming unverified. Let's try troubleshooting by following these steps:

**1. Update Extensions and Software**
Ensure that Dart and Flutter extensions are up to date in VS Code.
Ensure that your Flutter SDK is up to date by running **flutter upgrade** in your terminal.

**2. Verify Breakpoint Location**
Make sure the breakpoints are placed in a location in the code that is being executed. They should be inside a method that is getting called.

**3.Check launch.json Configuration**
Open or create a **launch.json** file in your **.vscode** directory and ensure it’s configured correctly. The configuration should look somewhat like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

**4. Check for Errors**
Check for any errors or warnings in your code that might prevent the debugger from attaching properly.

**5. Check the Debugger Console**
Look at the output in the debugger console in VS Code. It might have valuable information on why the breakpoints are not being hit.

**6. Try with a Physical Device**
If possible, try running your application on a physical device to see if the issue persists.

**7. Check Dart SDK Version**
Ensure that the Dart SDK version used in the project is compatible with the extension versions.

**8. Reset VS Code**
Try disabling and re-enabling the Dart and Flutter extensions.
Try reloading the VS Code window.

**9. Check Source File Mapping**
Ensure that the source file where you are setting breakpoints matches the file being executed. Sometimes, due to the build process, a different file might be executed.

**10. Reinstall Extensions**

- Consider uninstalling and reinstalling the Dart and Flutter extensions.

**11. Downgrade/Upgrade Extensions**
As a last resort, consider downgrading the Dart and Flutter extensions to a previous version where you didn’t face this issue.

After trying each step, attempt to debug again to see if the breakpoints are being hit. Hopefully, one of these steps helps resolve the issue you are facing.